# Can I use a single SharePoint Server for User Profile Synchronization?

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service

I have a test server and this server running central admin and SharePoint foundation Web Application service. Can I use this server for user profile synchronization service and user profile service application to import users & profile information from AD?

Comment: As Benny Skogberg mentioned, you can configure the service application. 
Consider that the User Profile Service Application is not available for SharePoint Foundation, but only for SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise and SharePoint Server 2013 Standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most definitely. First you install SharePoint 2013 in a [single server installation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262243.aspx) and when you're done, just configure [User Profile Service](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721052.aspx) with [User Profile Synchronization](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049.aspx), as in any other SharePoint Farm.

Just make sure it's for testing purpose only. You shouldn't use a single server install for production.